# I have cleaned vs 2015 Solution and exit without rebuilding the project

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I have cleaned project Solution and exit visual studio 2015 without rebuilding. when i reopened the project, the designer freezes.

Sorry for my English. let me try explain a bit

I am working with winForm project. I have accidentally deleted an image from **Resource** folder in the project explorer. Next i got error that tells that image 123.jpg is missing then i recopied the image file directly to the physical **Resource** directory. I hit Build solution but same error popped up. I clicked **Clean Solution** which it cleaned successfully. Then i clicked build. It popped up same error that image is missing though i have added.

After some struggles i clicked **FILE>CLOSE SOLUTION**. It popped up confirmation to save some **xx.Designer.cs**. I clicked YES but image is missing err popped up again. Next i click NO (Dont save) and closed The solution (No rebuild performed).

Next when i tried reopen, The visual studio 2015 completely frozen when it got loaded the project. I waited for +2hrs to respond with no success.. I killed it with TaskManager. Retried again and again with no success.

I backed up the whole project and then Deleted **.vs** folder in project root. Now The solution opens with no problem but when i click **View Designer**, It completely freezes.

Comment: You could try creating a new solution and copying the content from each of the files into a corresponding new file in the new solution.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The project  mostly consists of UserControls i tried to do that but with the new project when i copy UserContorls to the new project and double click the copied UserControls, the designer gets frozen in the new project.

Comment: Hm, it sounds like you have something in there that's causing an infinite loop in the designer.  The easiest solution might be to get a newer version of Visual Studio.

Comment: The `Resource` folder is just a repository. Adding an image there doesn't add it to the Project's Reources.

Comment: Add a new form and drag each of your usercontrols on until it freezes to see which control(s) is the issue.